# Chrome android keyboard input doesn't change back to text when leaving a numeric input field

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

Example:

```
<form novalidate>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cuvqkp14/

(visit on a tablet, Chrome desktop is not the issue)

When I have two or more inputs one of whose type is `tel` or whose inputmode is `numeric`, clicking the <kbd>Next</kbd> button on the Android keypad to navigate to the next field results in the `numeric` layout of the keyboard even if the next field is `type=text`, `type=email`, or inputmode = `text`. I have to click the ABC button to the left of the spacebar and then I am allowed to input alpha characters.

We have tested this across multiple Android tablets all running Android 8.0 and Chrome 70+

How can I force the keyboard layout back to alpha mode?

Comment: just tested on android 8.1 and 9.0 results:
8.1 - next button doesn't work at all - keyboard disappears after each next action but works for physical tab key - and then keyboard is in correct state for each field
9.0 everything works as expected

Comment: I tested on my android 8 mobile, it worked fined for me, I am using Gboard keyboard. maybe it got to do with the keyboard you are using?

Comment: I tested this on a Samsung Note 8, using SwiftKey Keyboard, Samsung Keyboard Neutral Beta, and Samsung Keyboard. I cannot reproduce. Tested in Google Chrome and Samsung Internet Browser.

Comment: Android Version 8, Samsung Experience Version 9, Build # R16NW.N950U1UES5CSA1

Comment: @Chris Which keyboard app do you use?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar issue on iPhone. And I have solved this problem on iPhone with adding from [pattern attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-pattern) to HTML element.

Try something like the following code with pattern attributes:

```html
<form novalidate>
  <p class="field">
    <label>Number: <input type="tel" name="number"></label>
  </p><p class="field">
    <label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
  </p><p class="field">
    <label>Phone Number: <input type="tel" name="phone"></label>
  </p><p class="field">
    <label>Street: <input type="text" name="street" inputmode="text" pattern=".*"></label>
  </p><p class="field">
    <label>Email Address: <input type="email" name="email" inputmode="email" pattern="[A-Z0-9a-z\.\-@]"></label>
  </p>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Unfortunately my Android system is a little bit old and I can not reproduce your issue – I have tried it with Chrome and Opera browsers. And I hope your issue will be solved with my code.

You can additionally try to use `inputmode="text"` and `inputmode="email"` atributes for this inputs. This is supported in Android Chrome and maybe it will work.

---

**My recommendation**

You can write your code also much shorter without `for="name"` (for label elements) and  `id="name"` (for input elements) attribute:

```
<label>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></label>
```

In this case it is the same like with this attributes.

Comment: I tried the pattern attribute and it did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: @Chris, You can additionally try to use `inputmode="text"` and `inputmode="email"` atributes for this inputs. I have added this to my answer. This is supported in Android Chrome and maybe it will work.

Answer (score 1):

tested on Android `9.0` with `GBoard` and Chrome `72.0.3626.76`, but were unable to reproduce the issue. however, attribute `inputmode` would be supported since Chrome for Android v `67` and this is the only alternative I could think of - except forcibly switching with `JS` on events `focus` & `blur`:

```
<input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*"/>
```

trying to reproduce the issue with the Android emulator might help to narrow it down to the cause... and I think so, because some devices come with a vendor-specific keyboard, which might react improperly to events emitted by Chrome. just recently I've noticed a slight difference in behavior, in between the input of `GBoard` and `SwiftKey`, when I was bounty hunting.

tying to "request desktop site" might also be worth an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('focus', function(event) {
  if (["INPUT", "TEXTAREA"].indexOf(event.target.tagName) != -1 && event.target.getAttribute('data-focused') != 'true') {
    event.target.blur();
    event.target.setAttribute('data-focused', 'true');
    setTimeout(function() {
      event.target.focus();
    }, 0);
  }
}, true);
document.addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  if (["INPUT", "TEXTAREA"].indexOf(event.target.tagName) != -1 && event.target.getAttribute('data-focused') == 'true') {
    event.target.removeAttribute('data-focused');
  }
}, true);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g34d0nsk/

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue while using the TouchPal Keyboard. Switching to a different keyboard (GBoard) resolved it, although it's confusing to me why. This seems like the responsibility of the browser to tell the keyboard which mode to be in.